# iOS9: Tiled images from asset catalog are repeating edge pixels (Xcode, Objective C)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, background

Here's a fun one: in iOS8, repeating an image was as simple as using 0px edge insets and setting the center to "Tiles." On iOS9 however, the images do not tile.  Instead, the blank space copies the edge pixel forever - and not from the sides I would expect:

[image: Incorrectly tiled:]

Perhaps I'm doing this wrong? Is there a *better* way to achieve a tiled background?

[image: Incorrectly tiled:]

Comment: if you do it programmatically, it will work. [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageName"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]; Problem is when such texture is used in launch screen.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. For some reason, if you **only slice the image horizontally**, the image tiles correctly. I DO NOT recommend this to anyone here looking for a quick fix, as I do not know how this affects previous versions of iOS. Or why it even works in the first place.  If anyone can provide a better answer, I'll accept it instead.

[image]

Comment: Still facing the same issue in iOS 11, this solution works

Comment: Still facing the same issue in iOS 12. Thanks for finding this solution.